# How would I get taxonomy info using the taxonomy term ID, in order to theme it?

Tags: 7, theming, taxonomy-terms

I need to be able to extract a taxonomy array and use it to create links.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[taxonomy_term_load()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--taxonomy--taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_term_load/7) looks promising.

> Return the term object matching a term ID.
>
> Parameters
>
> `$tid` A term's ID
>
> Return value
>
> A term object. Results are statically cached.

Comment: No problem @user840. Please check useful answers as answered.